# Visual Studio C++ "Calculate Code Metrics" not functional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview (16.11.0 Preview 1.0).

I'd like to calculate code metrics for a native C/C++ project but am having trouble. When starting Visual Studio the first time, I had the menu entry "Analyze > Calculate Code Metrics". When selected this created the tab "Code Metric Results" but it was empty. If I try to run again, the menu option was no longer available.

If I try the suggestion in the issue reported at the following link, the menu option reappears:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-find-analyze-code-metrics-menu/1033841

However, when I select the option I get a popup with the following error message:

> Cannot calculate code metrics because none of the selected projects support code metrics or Visual Studio is debugging an application.

I'm not debugging so my guess is that metrics are not supported in C/C++. Can someone confirm? If so, The documentation should state that and the option and tab should not be shown.

Comment: Did you had any success solving this? I encountered exactly the same issue today.

Comment: I could not find a definitive answer. Questions sent to Microsoft went unanswered. My understanding is that metrics is only supported for C# and not C++.

Comment: Yeah, I eventually found out the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Still in 2023, Microsoft does only support this functionality for C# and Visual Basic projects, as per : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Code-metrics-do-not-show-up/10335062